# What is the correct way to use Alert Dialog on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-context, android-dialog

So, i am trying to develop a little application on android, and i want to get a value from an alert dialog, the user has to choose a value between 2 integers. I am following the documentation, but i don't understand all the explanation. 
Here a part of my code, i don't know why it can't resolve the getActivity()

```
 else if (id == R.id.nav_HSL) {
        String dialog_message = "Select Value";
        String dialog_title = "HUE";

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(dialog_message).setTitle(dialog_title);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();


        image_bmp = HSV.changeHue(image_bmp);
        image.setImageBitmap(image_bmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is inside `Activity`, then you have to use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

This passes `Context` to `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor.

Your code would is valid in `Fragment`.